# problem with the relationship many to many in jhipster

Tags: many-to-many, jhipster, h2

I have a very painful error and i was searching for a solution since four days . So i want to do a many to many relationship with the jhipster commands between two entities folder and client , and the folder entity is the holder of the relationship . so after creating the relationship i tried to post a client but i get this error :

`could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into client (firstname, lastname, username, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement",`

when i tried to get a folder i get that error : 
`could not prepare statement; SQL [select distinct folder0_.id as id1_2_0_, client2_.id as id1_0_1_, folder0_.author as author2_2_0_, folder0_.deposit_date as deposit_3_2_0_, folder0_.identifier as identifi4_2_0_, folder0_.metadata_1 as metadata5_2_0_, folder0_.metadata_2 as metadata6_2_0_, folder0_.metadata_3 as metadata7_2_0_, client2_.firstname as firstnam2_0_1_, client2_.lastname as lastname3_0_1_, client2_.username as username4_0_1_, clients1_.folders_id as folders_1_3_0__, clients1_.clients_id as clients_2_3_0__ from folder folder0_ left outer join folder_client clients1_ on folder0_.id=clients1_.folders_id left outer join client client2_ on clients1_.clients_id=client2_.id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement",`

the code of the relationship in the two entities is the folowing :

the folder side : 
`@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "folder_client",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "folders_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "clients_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Client> clients = new HashSet<>();`

and the client side : 
`@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "clients")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Folder> folders = new HashSet<>();`

so does anybody have an idea on how to solve this problem ??? and thanks :) :)

Comment: Can you please post your entity JDL or JSON files (found in `.jhipster`) so we can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: It seems like SQL Grammar Exception. Your domain and SQL table fields are not matching. check again that field you will get the solution.